# Hibernate Update events vs. save events

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate with Spring and wonder how I can use the save or update event listeners vs. the save-update event listener.

My config looks like this:

```
<property name="eventListeners">
            <map>
                <entry key="save-update">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="com.test.MyTestSaveOrUpdateEventListener" />
                        <bean class="org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener" />
                    </list>
                </entry>
                <entry key="save">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener" />
                        <bean class="com.test.MyTestSaveEventListener" />
                    </list>
                </entry>
                <entry key="update">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultUpdateEventListener" />
                        <bean class="com.test.MyTestUpdateEventListener" />
                    </list>
                </entry>
            </map>

        </property>
```

The problem is that only the MyTestSaveOrUpdateEventListener bean gets called.

Does it really work like this:

- Using "saveOrUpdate" generates the save-update event
- Using "save" generates the save event

So when is the update event generated? I especially want to get the update event but it seems it never gets called.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Wild guess: when `update()` is called?

Comment: Probably, my problem is that why doesn't save-or-update generates an update event? Because in this project we dont use the "update" functions separately (we only use saveOrUpdate) yet we want to log the updates separately.

Comment: Then register your event listener for saveOrUpdate, since that's what you use. And override the appropriate methods (entityIsTransient, entityIsPersistent, etc.), or use getEntityState() to know what the state of the entity is. The javadoc and the source code are available.